# Is ATmega 328 on Arduino UNO already bootloaded?

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega328, bootloader

I've seen many tutorials on programming a ATmega 328 via Arduino. If i'm right, the atmega need to be bootloaded. I thought to remove the atmega present on the arduino board. But to bootloading atmega we need another atmega on the arduino board. I can't buy a new one. After bootloading we need only one IC. So, can I remove the atmega which  is present on the arduino and directly program it? Can I consider it as a bootloaded one?

Comment: The original question is not answered. User wants to know if he has bootloaded the 328chip on breadboard, then after putting this chip on UNO board will it be programmed through the normal way of programming Arduino Uno board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arduino controllers are usually already bootloaded with Arduino. So yeah, you can use the chip on the arduino. Or you can buy a programmer to bootloaded empty chips.

Answer (score 4):

In Arduino board, arduino controller means ATMEGA328P-PU already bootloaded. So, you can use directly. But if you buy only ATMEGA328P-PU chip or any other ATMEGA chip then you have to do bootloading for that.

Answer (score 2):

Arduino boards come with the bootloader already installed. You only need to flash a bootloader to it if something damaged the original one. When you buy replacement chips, you generally have a choice of "factory fresh" ones (no bootloader) or ones that already have a bootloader installed, at a small difference in price.